# Nilling out optional not working in BST implementation

Tags: swift, swift3, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, option-type

I am implementing a BST and working on the remove() function, problem is when I try to nil out the node to remove i.e. current, it still exists when I print the trees structure.

```
class Node<T : Comparable> {

    var value: T
    var left: Node<T>?
    var right: Node<T>?

    init(_ value:T) {
      self.value = value
    }
}

func remove(_ value:T) {

    var current: Node<T>? = root

    while let root = current {

        if value == root.value {
            if let _ = root.left, let right = root.right {

                let minValue = getMinValue(right)
                root.value = minValue
                remove(minValue)
            } else if let left = root.left {

                root.value = left.value
                root.left = nil
            } else if let right = root.right {

                root.value = right.value
                root.left = nil
            } else {
                //This doesn't remove the reference completely
                current = nil
            }

        } else if value > root.value {
            current = root.right
        } else {
            current = root.left
        }
    }
}
```

My print function still prints out the node I removed in the previous function

```
private func printTree(_ node:Node<T>?){

    guard let root = node else {
        return
    }
    print(root.value)
    printTree(root.right)
    printTree(root.left)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you just set the local variable `current` to `nil`. The parent node of `current` still has a reference of the node you are trying to remove.